# NSubstitute vs PRISM EventAggregator: Assert that calling a method triggers event with correct payload

Tags: c#, wpf, nunit, prism, nsubstitute

Consider the below method that updates a person and publishes an event through the PRISM EventAggregator to indicate that the person has been updated.

I would like to unit test that the message is sent with the correct payload. In this case that would mean the correct personId.

```
public void UpdatePerson(int personId)
{
    // Do whatever it takes to update the person
    // ...

    // Publish a message indicating that the person has been updated
    _eventAggregator
        .GetEvent<PersonUpdatedEvent>()
        .Publish(new PersonUpdatedEventArgs
        {
            Info = new PersonInfo
            {
                Id = personId,
                UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now
            };
        });
}
```

I know that I can create a substitute for the event aggregator:

```
var _eventAggregator = Substitute.For<IEventAggregator>();
```

However, I don't know how to detect when a message is sent and how to check its payload.

Comment: Do you want to test Prism's `EventAggregator`? If not, I suggest you assume that it works and just use it when you test your view model or whatever. Substituting for `IEventAggregator` won't help you testing the `EventAggregator` implementation, anyway :-) BTW - Prism comes with a nice set of tests, including the event stuff here https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Source/Prism.Tests/Events

Comment: But you probably don't need the event aggregator here, if you want to test whether `PersonUpdatedEventArgs` is created with the right values, check the resulting instance (and trust Prism to actually publish the event)...

Comment: How about posting the unit test you have now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an experienced unit tester so I'm not sure this is the correct unit test to write. But anyway, this is how I tested it so far and it seems to do what I want.

```
[Test]
public void TestPersonUpdateSendsEventWithCorrectPayload()
{
    // ARRANGE
    PersonUpdatedEventArgs payload = null;
    _eventAggregator
        .GetEvent<PersonUpdatedEvent>()
        .Subscribe(message => payload = message);

    // ACT
    _personService.UpdatePerson(5);

    // ASSERT
    payload.Should().NotBeNull();
    payload.Id.Should().Be(5);
}
```

Feedback welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually substitute away the event aggregator like this:

```
public class ToBeTested
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public ToBeTested( IEventAggregator eventAggregator )
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<OneEvent>().Publish( "test" );
    }
}

public class OneEvent : PubSubEvent<string>
{
}

[TestFixture]
internal class Test
{
    [Test]
    public void DoStuffTest()
    {
        var myEvent = new MyOneEvent();
        var myEventAggregator = Substitute.For<IEventAggregator>();
        myEventAggregator.GetEvent<OneEvent>().Returns( myEvent );

        var toBeTested = new ToBeTested( myEventAggregator );
        toBeTested.DoStuff();

        Assert.That( myEvent.ReceivedPayload, Is.EqualTo( "test" ) );
    }

    private class MyOneEvent : OneEvent
    {
        public override void Publish( string payload )
        {
            ReceivedPayload = payload;
        }

        public string ReceivedPayload
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
    }
}
```

Note the fake event class that's foisted on the subject under test to get access to the payload.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a subscriber to your unit test and check the result of the delegate.  See Prism's IEventAggregator unit tests as an example

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism.Tests/Events/PubSubEventFixture.cs#L14

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, using the real EventAggregator instead of a mock makes the tests much easier to write and read.
However, I stumbled over an issue where my tests would sometimes fail if they were ran as part of a test suite:

When subscribing to an event from test code (to assert that the code under test published the event correctly), the following additional parameters need to be provided to the Subscribe method:

```
event.Subscribe(..., 
                threadOption: ThreadOption.PublisherThread, 
                keepSubscriberReferenceAlive: true)
```

Otherwise, the test subscription was sometimes not triggered.

The authors of Prism do this in their own tests (https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/tests/Prism.Core.Tests/Events/PubSubEventFixture.cs)