# Exception on test of event aggregator subscriptions using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, prism, eventaggregator

Getting Not Supported exception while subscribing to fetch IEnumerable collection data with the below code. Not able to subscribe the published Collection object.

```
Mock<IEventAggregator> _mockEventAgg = new Mock<IEventAggregator>();
_mockEventAgg.Setup(x => x.GetEvent<ShowScreenEvent>().Publish(new ObservableCollection<Customer>()
              { 
                 // Customer properties or details     
              }));


_mockEventAgg.Setup(m => m.GetEvent<ShowScreenEvent>().Subscribe(It.IsAny<Action<IEnumerable<Customer>>>()))
             .Callback<IEnumerable<Customer>>(customers => SelectedCustomerData = customers);
```

Exception:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Moq.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: m => m.GetEvent().Subscribe(It.IsAny())

Comment: From reading the exception message, is `ShowScreenEvent.Subscribe()` non-virtual?

Comment: `ShowScreenEvent`  class is inherting  from `PubSubEvent<IEnumerable<Customer>>` class

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868184/nsubstitute-vs-prism-eventaggregator-assert-that-calling-a-method-triggers-even/35889556#35889556 (you can for sure transform this from NSubstitute to Moq)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add a parameter to the setup so that you are mocking the correct subscribe method.
in prism only one of the subscribe methods for an eent with a payload is marked as virtual

it would look something like this

```
Eventaggregator.Setup(c => c.GetEvent<YourEvent>()
                             .Subscribe(It.IsAny<Action<string>>(),
                                        It.IsAny<ThreadOption>(), 
                                        It.IsAny<bool>(),
                                        It.IsAny<Predicate<string>>()))
                .Returns(YourHandleFunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception you're getting says Moq is failing to set up a method because it is non-virtual.  Moq does not support mocking methods on a concrete type that are not marked `virtual`; [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5670902/1698557) for more information.

In your case, you're attempting to mock `ShowScreenEvent.Subscribe(...)`, which you say is defined on its base class, [`PubSubEvent<IEnumerable<Customer>>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn683969.aspx).   Indeed, it is non-virtual:

```
public SubscriptionToken Subscribe(Action<TPayload> action)
```