# How can I test function with prism event aggregator subscripe inside?

Tags: c#, moq, prism, xunit, eventaggregator

I use Xunit and Moq to test my application.
I am new at this topic...

Is it possible to test the method `DBConnector(...)` ?

And if yes, how?

I try it with mock... but the following line causes problems: Exception: System.NullReferenceException

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateSomeStateEvent>().Subscribe((x) => UpdateSomeState(x));
```

---

**Update**: Added the code for mock setup

`System.NullReferenceException` presumably fixed by this.

But now i get this exception:

> Unsupported expression: p => p.Subscribe (It.IsAny<Action>()). Non-overridable members (here: PubSubEvent.Subscribe) may not be used in setup / verification expression.

My code to be tested

```
public DBConnector(MyContext context , ILogger loggerFacade , IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
      mContext = context;
      mLoggerFacade = loggerFacade;
      mLoggerFacade.Log(LogLevel.Debug , "Some text");

      eventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateSomeStateEvent>().Subscribe((x) => UpdateSomeState(x));
    }

    private void UpdateSomeState(SomeState x)
    {
      SomeState = x;
    }
```

```
public class DBConnectorClassData : IEnumerable<object[]>
  {
    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
      var mLogger = new Mock<ILogger>();
      ILogger logger = mLogger.Object;

      var mEA = new Mock<IEventAggregator>();

      Mock<UpdateSomeStateEvent> mEvent = new Mock<UpdateSomeStateEvent>();
      
      Action<SomeState> callback = null;

      mEA.Setup(e => e.GetEvent<UpdateSomeStateEvent()).Returns(mEvent.Object);

               
      IEventAggregator eventAggregator = mEA.Object;

      var ctxt = new MyContext();
      
      yield return new object[]
        {
             new DBConnector(ctxt, logger, eventAggregator)
        };
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
  
  }
```

Comment: Where's the code that sets up `mEA.GetEvent`? Without setup, it returns `null` by default.

Comment: @Haukinger - thx! i added "mEA.GetEvent" ... but now i have the next error... I've updated my code above.

Comment: moq cannot setup non virtual members, normally one mocks interfaces. to just get the constructor to execute in the unit test, it shouldn't be necessary, though. `Subscribe` will be set up as no-op by default. If you want to test the actual subscription, have a look at my answer over there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868184/nsubstitute-vs-prism-eventaggregator-assert-that-calling-a-method-triggers-even/35889556#35889556

Comment: @Haukinger, I was thinking too complicated, thanks to your link I got it right.